# "Try...Catch" Block not Working with parseInt()

Tags: javascript

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have a javascript program that, when a button is clicked, takes in 4 strings from 4 text boxes in a form, and outputs those strings into a formatted textarea.

```
function testResults(form){
var errorhandle1 = parseInt(document.myForm.Item_Code.value);
var errorhandle2 = parseInt(document.myForm.Item_Cost.value);
var errorhandle3 = parseInt(document.myForm.Quantity.value);
//above variables are for error handling.
var d = "   ";
var subtotal = parseInt(form.Item_Cost.value) * parseInt(form.Quantity.value);
var subtotalValue = parseInt(document.myForm.Subtotal.value);
var testVar = "Item Code: " + form.Item_Code.value + d + 
              "Item Name: " + form.Item_Name.value + d + 
              "Item Cost: " + form.Item_Cost.value + d + 
              "Quantity: " + form.Quantity.value + '\n';


document.myForm.myTextarea.value += testVar;
document.myForm.Subtotal.value = parseInt(subtotal) + subtotalValue;
document.myForm.Sales_Tax.value =  document.myForm.Subtotal.value * salestax;
document.myForm.Total.value = parseInt(document.myForm.Subtotal.value) + parseFloat(document.myForm.Sales_Tax.value);
}
```

The above code works just fine, and does exactly what I want it to do for the scope of my program.

```
try {
    if ((isNaN(errorhandle3) == true) || (isNaN(errorhandle2) == true)) {
        throw "Error1";
    }
} catch (e) {
    if (e == "Error1") {
        alert("Error! You must enter a number into the qty and cost fields!");
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish with the try...catch block is simply to make sure that

```
document.myForm.Item_Code.value
document.myForm.Item_Cost.value
document.myForm.Quantity.value
```

are actually numbers.

The try...catch statements trigger every time I run the program and doesn't care what I put in the corresponding text boxes. I would greatly appreciate any and all insight on this!

Also: I looked at both of these links and was unable to understand my problem.
[javascript parseInt return NaN for empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736476/javascript-parseint-return-nan-for-empty-string)
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Comment: This makes no sense here to use `try/catch` around something this simple that doesn't by itself throw.  You can just use a straight `if` statement and the code will be simpler and perform better.  I don't see any need for exceptions here.

Comment: Tip: don’t test booleans against `== true`. It’s redundant; `if (isNaN(errorhandle3) || isNaN(errorhandle2))` reads better.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick reply. I'm in the process of changing those now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your root problem here is that `isNaN()` tests to see if the value is `NaN`.  It does not test to see if a string is a proper number.  It has some coercion rules to try to deal with strings, but that really isn't what it is designed for.

You can see ways to test if something can be parsed into a valid number here: [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

It's worth reading the detail in the good answers there, but it boils down to something like this which is a bit more than you need, but is general purpose:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

And, then there's no reason to use exceptions in your code, so you can just do this:

```
if (!isNumber(errorhandle3) || !(isNumber(errorhandle2)) {
   alert("Error! You must enter a number into the qty and cost fields!");
}
```

---

Also, in your code, some `.Value` properties look like maybe they should be `.value` (lowercase).

Comment: I think this is my problem, trying that now.

Comment: @Fishbones - also maybe `.Value` should be `.value`.

Comment: However, you cannot actually "input" an infinity number to a form field :D

Comment: @LeoDeng - yeah, I know - this is a generic function to have around that will work here too.

Comment: Before that he uses `parseInt`, which returns a proper number, or an `NaN`. So check with `isNaN` is enough.

Comment: Thank you all, you definitely solved my nightmare problem. I didn't actually know that `isFinite` existed either.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code block

```
var errorhandle2 = parseInt(document.myForm.Item_Cost.Value);
var errorhandle3 = parseInt(document.myForm.Quantity.Value);
```

You are using `Value`, which should be `value`, that's case-sensitive.

By the way, `isNaN` returns boolean, you don't have to compare with `true`