# Stacking jQuery CSS declaration doesn't work in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

This fiddle provides a stripped-down example of what I'm trying to achieve. A lot is missing, but all relevant code is there.

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysx0bp5d/2/). The goal is that the pink box fills up the space that's available in width (with a gap defined in CSS by `margin-left`) and that it has the same height as the yellow part. Unfortunately only the first property (`min-height`) is applied.

```
$(".banana + .strawberry").css({
    "minHeight": function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            banana = $this.prev(".banana"),
            bh = banana.outerHeight();
        return bh;
    },
    "width": function () {
        // Many variables, but they allow a highly
        // customized CSS file
        var $this = $(this),
            margin_l = parseInt($this.css("marginLeft"), 10),
            margin_r = parseInt($this.css("marginRight"), 10),
            padding_l = parseInt($this.css("paddingLeft"), 10),
            padding_r = parseInt($this.css("paddingRight"), 10),
            border_l = parseInt($this.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10),
            border_r = parseInt($this.css("borderRightWidth"), 10),
            parent = $(this).parent(),
            pw = parent.width(),
            banana = $this.prev(".banana"),
            bw = banana.outerWidth();

        console.log(margin_l);
        return (pw - bw - margin_l - margin_r - padding_l - padding_r - border_l - border_r);
    }
});
```

For some reason all browsers accept this code, however IE8 doesn't. On my website I'm using jQuery 1.11.2. I tested IE8 in emulation mode. I also tried alerting some text inside the `function` that ought to return the right value for width, but even that doesn't work. Can't you stack CSS properties in jQuery with IE8 that all depend on a function to return a value?

Comment: will it help if you also include jquery migrate?

Comment: Just wondering... What is the return of th? I'm not seeing any th variable.

Comment: @sdcr [No, it doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/ysx0bp5d/3/).

Comment: @dowomenfart Small error, fixed and edited Fiddle as well.

Comment: I'm trying to load this fiddle in IE 8 and IE 10 and it's not loading anything. Stuck on loading screen.

Comment: IE returns "NaN" on margin_r, border_l and border_r so this answer may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6736521/2359055](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6736521/2359055)

Comment: @dowomenfart [This](https://jsfiddle.net/ysx0bp5d/3/embedded/result/) should work.

Comment: @AbrahamUribe adding ` || 0` after the `parseInt`'s did work. I don't understand why though. When no border is set, IE8 and lower return NaN? But more recent versions don't? Seems like something jQuery should've taken care of with a custom parseInt function.

Comment: IE8 and lower return "auto" on $this.css("marginRight") and parseInt("auto") return NaN so you can also set the default margin-right to 0 in CSS

Comment: @AbrahamUribe Ah, I see. Thanks! If you could post that as answer, I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 and lower return "auto" (default value) on `$this.css("marginRight")` and "medium" on `$this.css("borderRightWidth")` and `$this.css("borderLeftWidth")` so `parseInt("auto")` and `parseInt("medium")` will return NaN
you can set the default value of those properties on CSS to 0 like this

```
.strawberry {
    background: #FC5A8D;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}
```

or you can add `|| 0` after each `parseInt()` so each var defaults to 0 instead of NaN like this

```
$(".banana + .strawberry").css({
    "minHeight": function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            banana = $this.prev(".banana"),
            bh = banana.outerHeight();
        return bh;
    },
    "width": function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            margin_l = parseInt($this.css("marginLeft"), 10)||0,
            margin_r = parseInt($this.css("marginRight"), 10)||0,
            padding_l = parseInt($this.css("paddingLeft"), 10)||0,
            padding_r = parseInt($this.css("paddingRight"), 10)||0,
            border_l = parseInt($this.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10)||0,
            border_r = parseInt($this.css("borderRightWidth"), 10)||0,
            parent = $(this).parent(),
            pw = parent.width(),
            banana = $this.prev(".banana"),
            tw = banana.outerWidth();        
            return (pw - tw - margin_l - margin_r - padding_l - padding_r - border_l - border_r);
    }
});
```