# Why parseInt(key) === NaN always evaluates to false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing decision based on dictionary key, i have only two types of keys, numeric and alpha,

```
var _dict = { 'a':'one', 'b':'two', '1':'three' };

$.each( _dict, function( key, value ){

  if( parseInt( key ) === NaN ) {

     // this statement always evalute to false

    } else {

    }

});
```

if i print `console.log(parseInt('a'))`, it will also return `NaN`

I alreay found the solution from this question [javascript parseInt return NaN for empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736476/javascript-parseint-return-nan-for-empty-string)

But i was wondering why it always evaluates to false.

Comment: `NaN != NaN`, use `isNaN(parseInt( key ))`  or in your case `!parseInt( key )`

Comment: because IEEE 754 said so

Comment: and NaN !== NaN because so it was in the beginning and to change it now may break the www's (or parts of it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `NaN` is defined to be not equal to anything (including itself). Check it:

```
>> NaN === NaN
False
```

You should use isNaN() function instead:

```
>> isNaN(NaN)
true
>> isNaN(0/0)
true
>> isNaN(parseInt('a'))
true
```